# rrule Day of Week after Nth Day of Month

Tags: python-dateutil, rrule

What is the best way to write an rrule that is Tuesday after the third Monday each June?

Currently I write the rule like this:

```
rule_mo = rrule(freq=YEARLY,              
            bymonth=6, 
            byweekday=MO(+3),
            ...)
rule = (x + relativedelta(weekday=TU(+1)) for x in rule_mo)
```

Is there a way to write this entire rule using just the `rrule` and not having to use the second pass with the `relativedelta`?

Comment: isn't it similar to 3rd tuesday (tuesday after third monday) of every june ?

Comment: The third Tuesday and the Tuesday after the third Monday are not the same.

Comment: not clear, can you give me example please

Comment: If the first day of the month is a Tuesday, then the Tuesday after the third Monday will actually be the fourth Tuesday.

Comment: check this link http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/rrule.html, here there is example "Every four years, the first Tuesday after a Monday in November,forever (U.S. Presidential Election day):", i tried similar rule but couldn't exact one, but i am sure this is very similar you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Reference : http://jkbr.github.io/rrule/

```
rule = RRule.fromText("every June on 3rd Tuesday")

rule.origOptions    
{
   freq: RRule.YEARLY,
   bymonth: [6],
   byweekday: [RRule.TU.nth(3)]
}

rule.toString()     

FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=6;BYDAY=+3TU

rule.toText()   every June on the 3rd Tuesday
```

Comment: Sorry for necropost, but  the link in the answer is broken. Here's a working reference: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html